# How to increase count and store into firebase database by clicking a button?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    mImageLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mProcessLike = true;
            //mLikeCount.setText("numLikes");
            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if(mProcessLike)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                        {
                            mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                            numLike--;
                            mProcessLike = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Liked");
                            mProcessLike = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });

            mDatabaseLike.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {
                    numLike = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child("numLike").setValue(numLike);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hi, thanks for reading. I am new to Android and Firebase and I was struggling with increasing count when like button is pressed and store that count number into the database "Like". I have declared DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike and it looks like this. [image: mDatabaseLike]

I am trying to count the number of children in each like(the ones with "Liked" string) and store them into each key(ex. Kb6cSLImN_7lrPyAr2Q) as numLike. When I click like button, it updates the count, but when I click the button again to remove that like, the number doesn't decrease.

Please help!. Thank you very much.

Comment: You'll want to also implement `onChildRemoved` for that, since removing a like will trigger that method.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. but, when I click the button again, the child is removed, but the program reads onChildAdded method again. onChildRemoved is not read at all. Do you recognize the reason?

Comment: For the above example, how can I know if a1LSTrDQXRRX6glW3K7arWwlkwm1 is removed? I noticed that onChildRemoved occurs when -Kb6cSLlmN-7lrPyAr2Q is deleted.